# Compare items between two instances

Tags: powershell-extensions, content-migration

We upgraded Sitecore 8.2 project to 9.1. Upgrade took around 1 month to finish and during this period, authors created/updated some items in old instance and they didn't  make a note of those items.

So, now I want to compare both instances to find out items to migrate content from 8.2 to 9.1

Is there any way to find out what items got updated/created in old instance? Can this be done using Sitecore Powershell Remoting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options included with SPE out-of-the-box which could aid in accomplishing this task. The detail below is produced with SPE 6.0 but much of it was available in previous versions.

#### Reports

There is a **Content Report** called *Items last updated* which can be used to find any items in the tree (typically content) that has changed after a specified date.

[image: Example filtering criteria[1]]

#### Comparing Instances

The following script provides a basic example at using SPE to compare the content between two instances beginning with the specified root item.

```powershell
Clear-Host
$watch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

$Username = "admin"
$Password = "b"
$Source = "https://abc.dev.local"
$Destination = "https://123.dev.local"

$localSession = New-ScriptSession -user $Username -pass $Password -conn $Source
$remoteSession = New-ScriptSession -user $Username -pass $Password -conn $Destination


$rootId = "{37D08F47-7113-4AD6-A5EB-0C0B04EF6D05}"

$sourceItemIds = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $localSession -ScriptBlock { 
    $rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $using:rootId

    $itemIds = (@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants()) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID) -join "|"
    $itemIds
} -Raw

$destinationItemIds = Invoke-RemoteScript -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    $rootItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $using:rootId

    $itemIds = (@($rootItem) + @($rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants()) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID) -join "|"
    $itemIds
} -Raw

$referenceIds = $sourceItemIds.Split("|", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
$differenceIds = $destinationItemIds.Split("|", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

$queueIds = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $referenceIds -DifferenceObject $differenceIds | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

$watch.Stop()
$totalSeconds = $watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000
Write-Host "$($totalSeconds) seconds" -ForegroundColor Yellow
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Sitecore stackexchange.

RAZL [RAZL](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Razl) - can be used to compare the items between two different Sitecore Instances. Please note this is a "paid" software.

Another option is to use [Sitecore Courier](https://github.com/adoprog/Sitecore-Courier) - This open source module can compare sitecore serialized files in two folders and create a diff (update) package containing the differences.

There is also more information on this other post which you can refer - [Comparing a Sitecore instance with a vanilla one](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5046/comparing-a-sitecore-instance-with-a-vanilla-one)