# Get list of Sitecore items updated by Specific User

Tags: content-editor, workflow

My project is running on Sitecore 9, before 10 days I deployed changes on production environment after that content editor started updating content on production, we have created new user and that user also updated content and all items were not in workflow that's they got published to **Web** database, so we want to validate changes that he made.

Is there any way in Sitecore to get a list of updated items by a specific user on specific dates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below PowerShell to get a list of items updated by a specific user in last X days

**Script**

```
$path ="master:/sitecore/content"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | 
            Where-Object { $_.__Updated -gt [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-10) -and $_."__Updated By" -eq "sitecore\username" } 

ForEach ($item in $items) 
{
    Write-Host $item.ID $item.Paths.Path
}

Write-Host "Updated items count : " $items.Count
```

[ASR module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Advanced_System_Reporter.aspx) also has an inbuild report to get the last modified items in X days but I have not tested the module with Sitecore 9.

Comment: i was searching for this for a while !!Thanks Surya!!

Answer (score 7):

Sitecore PowerShell Extensions includes a report out-of-the-box for items last updated since a specified time. Screenshots taken with SPE 5.1.

I shared using this report for a similar issue where the developer needs to [compare between two instances of Sitecore](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/compare-items-between-two-instances/22373#22373).

[image]

[image]

[image]